# Parsing XML with repeated element names in R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to parse Eve killog data using R and I am running into issues extracting the data because the file uses the same rowset tag repeatedly within one kill.

This is an excerpt from the XML (full example found [here](http://wiki.eve-id.net/APIv2_Char_KillLog_XML)):

```
  <rowset name="kills" key="killID" columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID">
  <row killID="63" solarSystemID="30000848" killTime="2007-11-15 15:36:00" moonID="0">
    <victim characterID="150340823" characterName="Dieinafire" corporationID="1000169"
            corporationName="Center for Advanced Studies" allianceID="0"
            allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName=""
            damageTaken="6378" shipTypeID="12003" />
    <rowset name="attackers" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,
            factionID,factionName,securityStatus,damageDone,finalBlow,weaponTypeID,shipTypeID">
      <row characterID="0" characterName="" corporationID="1000127" corporationName="Guristas"
           allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0" 
           damageDone="6313" finalBlow="1" weaponTypeID="0" shipTypeID="203" />
      <row characterID="0" characterName="" corporationID="150279367" corporationName="Starbase Anchoring Corp"
           allianceID="0" allianceName="" securityStatus="0" damageDone="65" finalBlow="0"
           weaponTypeID="0" shipTypeID="16632" />
    </rowset>
```

My goal is to get something like this for each kill:

```
killID               63
solarSystemID        30000848 
victim characterID   Dieinafire
attacker characterID ""
attacker characterID ""
```

I can extract the victim information like this:

```
xpathSApply(xmlFile, "//victim", xmlGetAttr, 'characterName')
```

because there is only one victim, but I dont know how to extract the attacker information. I tried this:

```
xpathSApply(xmlFile, "//rowset/row/", xmlGetAttr, 'characterName')
```

but I got a lot of null responses. Can someone suggest a clean way to extract attacker information for each kill?

Comment: you get a lot of null responses because a lot of attributes values for 'characterName' are empty. I don't know what is "attacker information". Btw, the xml code you posted is broken (the one you linked is valid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, I ran it on the total XML, not the excerpt :

```
#finds nodes that have a `killID` attribute
data<-t(xpathSApply(xmlFile,"//row[@killID]",function(x){
  #gets the killI
  killID<-xpathSApply(x, ".", xmlGetAttr, 'killID')
  #gets the victimName
  victimName<-xpathSApply(x, "./victim", xmlGetAttr, 'characterName')
  #gets the attackers and pastes them together
  attackersId<-paste0(getNodeSet(x,"rowset[@name='attackers']/row/@characterID"),collapse=",")
  return(list(killID,victimName,attackersId))
}
))
colnames(data)<-c("KillID","victimName","attackersID")
data
```